# Why does not show my token balances and the other information it on Ropsten?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I published an custom ERC20 token contract in Ropsten network and functions are working of the contract correctly. I minted the 100 token to an address an checked total supply result is 100 too. And then I checked balance of the token receiver address, it's 100.

but both token total supply, holders, balances and receiver token balance are **zero** on Ropsten explorer?

what is my mistake? why don't they show on Ropsten?

thank you.

Comment: Can you please share your contract address on Ropsten?

Comment: hey I solved this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a transfer for the explorer to register that data.